# Error in rotation 13 cipher code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was doing some competitive programming and stumbled upon a ROT13 question that required me to increment each alphabet by 13.

This was my attempt

```
def rot13(message):
    l2 = []
    l1 = list(message)
    for i in l1:
        i = str(i)
    for i in l1:
        if ord('a') <= ord(i) <= ord('z'):
            i = chr((ord(i) + 13) % 26 + ord('a'))
            l2.append(i)
        elif ord('A') <= ord(i) <= ord('Z'):
            i = chr((ord(i) + 13) % 26 + ord('A'))
            l2.append(i)
    return l2
```

It was returning wrong outputs such as

For input - test , it gave output - zkyz while correct is "grfg"

For input - Test , output was Tkyz while it should be Grfg

I haven't joined the list yet as I was first trying to get the right answer.

Comment: You forget to *subtract* the initial value from the characters so `'A'` starts out as 65, not 0.

Comment: @shawnin damnen If you are looking for a reference take a look at the [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py#L23) module implementation.

Comment: @usr2564301 Which is why I have added it at the end to give it the unicode integer value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the corrected code:

```
def rot13(message):
    l2 = []
    l1 = list(message)
    for i in l1:
        if ord('a') <= ord(i) <= ord('z'):
            i = chr((ord(i) - ord('a') + 13) % 26 + ord('a'))  # <== changed
            l2.append(i)
        elif ord('A') <= ord(i) <= ord('Z'):
            i = chr((ord(i) - ord('A') + 13) % 26 + ord('A'))  # <== changed
            l2.append(i)
    return l2
```

and a test run:

```
>>> rot13('Test')
['G', 'r', 'f', 'g']
```

The issue was that `ord('a')` or `ord('A')` needed to be subtracted from the initial *ord()* call.   You were pretty close.  Except for this nit, it all worked :-)

Comment: @shawnindamnen Please mark the answer as the selected answer.  Thx.

Comment: Why the first `for`-loop?

Comment: @FredrikHedman I just took that out.  It was there because it was in the OP's code and I wanted to make the minimal edits required to make it work.   But, yes, that loop was likely superfluous.

Comment: Yes.  However, this solution will drop any charachter that is not [a-zA-Z].  For example `rot13('Smörgåsbord')`.